# CS2002 warning output when using EmbeddedResource

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

## What I have tried

The following settings in csproj are used to create resource files from plain text and generate strongly typed files.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\MyResources.restext">
    <StronglyTypedLanguage>C#</StronglyTypedLanguage>
    <StronglyTypedFileName>Resources\MyResources.Designer.cs</StronglyTypedFileName>
    <StronglyTypedNamespace>$(RootNamespace).Resources</StronglyTypedNamespace>
    <StronglyTypedClassName>MyResources</StronglyTypedClassName>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

There is no problem with the resource generation itself, but CS2002 is output for MyResources.Designer.cs.

## Questions

What settings can I use to prevent warnings from being output?

Comment: Hi, is there something like <Compile Include="Resources\MyResources.Designer.cs" />
 in you csproj file? :)

Comment: By the way, you can check the build process to see why the cs file was been compiled twice, this is the official docuement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs2002

Comment: <Compile Include="Resources\MyResources.Designer.cs" /> does not exist. Full source code is at https://github.com/usausa/WorkEmbeddedResource